# Creating a build configuration ID

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Brand new to teamcity (~2hours), and I ran into a problem. How does one generate or create a "Build Configuration ID"?  After searching google and stack, there doesn't seem to be much more than documentation of what it is.  Is this something very simple, or can I just make up my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a build configuration, it will pretty much get automatically generated from the Parent(s) and Config Name

[image]

You can edit this field if you want.

Comment: Oh, yeah, wow.  That was easy. Thanks man.  I just assumed I had to find that somewhere.